# (Angular) Accessing Typescript object in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Can't seem to get my modal to access a javascript object in the controller, and populate fields accordingly.

**What I've accomplished:**

- Made a component that displays a list of "person" objects.
- Click a row on that list, and have a modal come up.

**What I can't seem to do:**

- Have the modal populate based on the "person" I clicked.  (I am using the modal as a client detail card).

**What I've tried:**

- I tried creating a method in my controller which takes the "person"
  object for the row, and assigns it to a variable in my controller,
  but I cannot seem to get my modal to update based on this variable.

**TL,DR:** Being a beginner in angular, what's the most simple way to have a bootstrap modal access an object located in it's controller?

Code References:

**Html:**

```
<div>
<!--Grid column-->
<div class="mx-auto my-auto animated fadeIn col-lg-12">

    <!--Card-->
    <div class="card card-cascade">

        <!--Card Header-->
        <div class="view gradient-card-header blue-gradient pt-4 text-center text-white">

            <!--Table-->
            <table class="table table-hover table-respsonsive">

                    <!--Table head-->
                    <thead class="blue-grey lighten-4">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Person ID</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Middle Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Date of Birth</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <!--Table head-->

                    <!--Table body-->
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="pt-auto" *ngFor= "let person of persons">

                            <!--Non-Edit Mode Values-->
                            <td *ngIf="!editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)" (click)="onOpenProfileModule(person); style.show()">{{person.Person_Id}}</td>
                            <td *ngIf="!editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)" (click)="onOpenProfileModule(person); style.show()">{{person.First_Name}}</td>
                            <td *ngIf="!editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)" (click)="onOpenProfileModule(person); style.show()">{{person.Middle_Name}}</td>
                            <td *ngIf="!editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)" (click)="onOpenProfileModule(person); style.show()">{{person.Last_Name}}</td>
                            <td *ngIf="!editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)" (click)="onOpenProfileModule(person); style.show()">{{person.Date_Of_Birth | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
                            <td *ngIf="!editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)" (click)="onOpenProfileModule(person); style.show()">{{person.Gender}}</td>

                            <!--Edit Mode Values-->
                            <td [hidden]="!editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)">{{person.Person_Id}}</td>
                            <td [hidden]="!editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)"><input type="text" id="firstNameUpdate" class="form-control" #firstNameUpdate value="{{person.First_Name}}"></td>
                            <td [hidden]="!editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)"><input type="text" id="middleNameUpdate" class="form-control" #middleNameUpdate value="{{person.Middle_Name}}"></td>
                            <td [hidden]="!editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)"><input type="text" id="lastNameUpdate" class="form-control" #lastNameUpdate value="{{person.Last_Name}}"></td>
                            <td [hidden]="!editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)"><input type="date" id="dateOfBirthUpdate" class="form-control" #dateOfBirthUpdate value="{{person.Date_Of_Birth | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}"></td>
                            <td [hidden]="!editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)"><input type="text" id="genderUpdate" class="form-control" #genderUpdate value="{{person.Gender}}"></td>

                            <!--Action Buttons-->
                            <td class="text-center">

                                <!--Open Edit Mode Button-->
                                <a *ngIf="!editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)" class="green-text px-2" style="font-size: 150%;" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" (click) = "onEditClicked(person.Person_Id, null, null, null, null, null)">
                                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                </a>

                                <!--Close Edit Mode Button-->
                                <a *ngIf="editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)" class="green-text px-2" style="font-size: 150%;" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Save Changes" (click) = "onEditClicked(person.Person_Id, firstNameUpdate.value, middleNameUpdate.value, lastNameUpdate.value, dateOfBirthUpdate.value, genderUpdate.value)">
                                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                </a>

                                <!--Delete Button-->
                                <a class="red-text px-2" style="font-size: 150%;" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove" (click) = "onDeletePerson(person.Person_Id); onGetPersons()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                </a>



                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <!--Add New Client Entry Fields-->
                        <tr class = "pt-auto">
                            <td></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" #firstName></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="middleName" class="form-control" #middleName></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="lastName" class="form-control" #lastName></td>
                            <td><input type="date" id="dateOfBirth" class="form-control" #dateOfBirth></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="gender" class="form-control" #gender></td>

                            <td class="text-center">
                                <a class="green-text px-1" style="font-size: 150%;" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add"(click) = "onAddPerson(firstName.value, middleName.value, lastName.value, dateOfBirth.value, gender.value)">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus mt-3"></i>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <!--Table body End-->
                </table>
                <!--Table End-->
            </div>
            <!--Table Wrapper End-->

        </div>
        <!--/.Card content-->

    </div>
    <!--/.Card-->

</div>
<!--Grid column-->

<!--Add Profile Modal-->
<div mdbModal #style="mdb-modal" class="modal fade" id="centralModalInfo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-notify modal-info" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <p class="heading lead">{{personWhosContactIsBeingUpdated.First_Name}}</p>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="style.hide()">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-check fa-4x mb-3 animated rotateIn"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit iusto nulla aperiam blanditiis ad consequatur in dolores culpa, dignissimos, eius non possimus fugiat. Esse ratione
                        fuga, enim, ab officiis totam.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>Get it now <i class="fa fa-diamond ml-1"></i></a>
                <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="style.hide()" mdbWavesEffect>No, thanks</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

**Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PersonsService } from '../services/persons.service';
import { Person } from 'models/person.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-persons-directory',
  templateUrl: './persons-directory.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./persons-directory.component.scss'],
  providers: [PersonsService]
})
export class PersonsDirectoryComponent implements OnInit {

  persons = [];
  isEditModeEnabled: boolean = false;
  idOfItemBeingEdited: number;
  personWhosContactIsBeingUpdated: Person;


  constructor(private personservice: PersonsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onGetPersons();
  }

  onGetPersons() {
    this.personservice.getPersons()
    .subscribe(
     (response: any[]) => {this.persons = response;
       console.log(this.persons);},
     (error) => (console.log(error))
   );
 }

  onOpenProfileModule(person: Person){
    this.personWhosContactIsBeingUpdated = person;
    console.log(person + "is being added to " + this.personWhosContactIsBeingUpdated);
  }

}
```

Comment: do you get the current person in console?

Comment: Yes.  If you are referring to : console.log(person + "is being added to " + this.personWhosContactIsBeingUpdated);

Comment: Unless you need to roll your own, it's probably easier to use a modal from a library. I use the one from https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/

Comment: I am using the mdb-bootstrap pro modal.  My problem is only that trying to add a field like {{personWhosContactIsBeingUpdated.First_Name}} returns me with an error for cannot find First_Name of undefined.

Comment: try ```{{personWhosContactIsBeingUpdated?.First_Name}}```

Comment: What does the ? do.

Comment: @NickGrover it checks if ```personWhosContactIsBeingUpdated``` is defined and exist or not then if it's not undefined tries to access ```First_Name``` property and prevent run time errors.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying at use {{personWhosContactIsBeingUpdated.First_Name}} which gave error cannot find First_Name of undefined.  By changing to {{personWhosContactIsBeingUpdated?.First_Name}}, the error was gone and my modal now updates correctly.